# Stop paper ejecting after print the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I am a beginner programmer. I am using a dot matrix printer. When I taking a print it ejects paper till reaches A4 length. I just want to print 3 to 6 lines only. And to stop the page ejection just after this. I searched for an answer, I found to use "page-break-after: always".
The following div contains the print content.

```
<div class="print_bill"></div>
```

The css

```
@media print,screen{
 .print_bill {
   position: relative;
   page-break-after: always;
 }
}
```

But It was not success. please help me

Comment: I assume an empty div is not all that's on your page. What more do you have?

Comment: I'm afraid you may have to change your printer settings to make it believe the paper is 1" high.

Comment: `page-break-after` does not behave this way. To achieve this effect you need to tell your printer, through the printer setting the size paper you wish to print. This is a problem because you can't effect how the printer prints through a web browser using JavaScript. You are going to have to find a different solution that allows you to manipulate the print driver.

Comment: 3-6 lines I means not only this. It is a Bill. It contains headers and footers. So it may totally 4 to 5 inches in length. (Not 1" height)

Comment: @FirosFab if you got any solution for this type of requirement please share it. I need it urgently.